# More scalaish way to test if a Some(object) is None and get element

Tags: scala

Say I have a `val a: Option[A]` and I want to get A.name

```
a match {
  case None => ""
  case Some(o) => o.name
}
```

How to write it shortly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
a map(_.name) getOrElse ""
```

Comment: You can replace a combination of `map` and `getOrElse` with `fold`. E.g., `a.fold("")(_.name)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do nothing if it's `None`, use `a.foreach(o => println(o.name))`

updated:

you can learn more usage of `Option` in the API doc: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option